# Re-position Spring Roo generated Apache Tiles View

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles, spring-roo

A very simple question. I do not know Apache Tiles.

For a Spring Roo generated web app the views are created using Apache Tiles. The classic layout with the menu on the left is created.

**I want to have the menu (menu.jspx) appear on the right hand side of the page instead of the classic left hand side. How do I do this?**

I have read the Apache Tiles tutorial on the main web site, however the description there uses jsp and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to edit the standard.css file menu items.

I got to thinking that all of the jspx elements are controlled by the css files. Sounds like a no brainer no but I am use to using html tables to do all of the ui work, not css.

So, I found a place http://csscreator.com/node/461 that had some sample code and I modified it for the standard.css menu elements and below is what I pasted in. Its not perfect but it is a  place to begin.

```
#menu {
background-image: none;
position: absolute;
right:0px;
width: 525px;
top: 80px;
height: 15px;
display: inline;
}

#menu ul{
padding: 3px 5px;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `alt` theme in Spring Roo default generated User Interface.

It has the menu to the right. Go ahead and customize.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for moving around the menu is to modify the css as you have described above. However you also have the option of changing where the menu appears in the html source by modifying the page layout file.  This can be found under WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx.

You could then choose to use a table based html layout if that was your preferred option.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to select the "alt" option on the page which will auto-change to the layout you want.

If you then make that the default layout instead